# favicon / start sreens for all browsers and devices

Tags: html, css, icons, favicon

I was wondering if i have everything covered to include all favicons / start splash screens for all browsers and devices?

Is this enough? Or what are the main ones I should be covering? Am i missing any below:

```
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicons/favicon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/favicons/touch-icon-iphone.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/images/favicons/touch-icon-ipad.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/images/favicons/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/images/favicons/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
  <meta name="application-name" content="site">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/images/favicons/msapplication-tiny.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/images/favicons/msapplication-square.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/images/favicons/msap   plication-wide.png">
  <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/images/favicons/msapplication-large.png">
```

Thanks

Comment: you can use .ico file instead of .png images for favicon. Because some browser do not display .png images.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a code review.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Classic favicon for desktop browsers**

Drop a `favicon.ico` file in the root directory of your web site. [It does not need to be declared](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_ico_not_declared) and [it is expected to contain 16x16, 32x32 and 48x48 pictures](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_ico_so_big).

Modern browsers will also look for PNG icons. You can address most cases with:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
```

**iOS**

If you combine iOS 6 and iOS 7 sizes, iPad and iPhone, and Retina and non-Retina, that gives you 8 [Apple touch icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html):

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
```

**Android**

Android Chrome uses the Apple touch icon. But it also documents a [196x196 PNG icon](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen) that will replace the touch icon... someday. So:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-196x196.png" sizes="196x196">
```

**Windows 8.0 tile picture**

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
```

**Windows 8.1 tile pictures**

```
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/images/favicons/msapplication-tiny.png">
<meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/images/favicons/msapplication-square.png">
<meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/images/favicons/msapplication-wide.png">
<meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/images/favicons/msapplication-large.png">
```

or use a `browserconfig.xml` dropped in the root of your web site (or declared in the `head` section), with the following content:

```
<browserconfig>
  <msapplication>
    <tile>
      <square70x70logo src="/mstile-70x70.png"/>
      <square150x150logo src="/mstile-150x150.png"/>
      <square310x310logo src="/mstile-310x310.png"/>
      <wide310x150logo src="/mstile-310x150.png"/>
      <TileColor>#da532c</TileColor>
    </tile>
  </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

**The other guys**

What about Google TV, Opera Speed dials and others? They expect PNG icons:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-160x160.png" sizes="160x160">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-96x96.png" sizes="96x96">
(...)
```

**Generate these pictures and HTML code**

[You can generate all these pictures and HTML code at once](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for taking the time to explain all the possibilities! Could the xml file be used to specify ALL of the above with one line to the xml file rather than including all the above lines within the head area of the html?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. browserconfig.xml was made by Microsoft for Windows 8. As far as I know, only W8 processes it. And don't count on Apple or Google to support it :)

Comment: It is important to only use a single rel="icon" link.Many browsers load them all!  I just checked the latest version of Microsoft Edge and Chrome both load every single instance of rel="icon".

If you're looking to reduce bandwidth here, you're clearly doing it wrong if you include multiple versions.  I would suggest just including single versions of the largest icon you want to include, otherwise including them all gives you the worst possible bandwidth outcome and one you might not expect at all

Comment: Firefox: true, and this is sad (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751712, opened three years ago). Chrome: same issue (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=324820), but I haven't been able to reproduce it for at least a year. At the moment, it loads `favicon.ico`, and only this icon. Edge: I couldn't test because of its URL restrictions. However, IE11 loads the 32x32 PNG icon, and only this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ico instead of .png in the first line

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicons/favicon.ico">
```