# Favicon not showing up when saving the page to the home screen using chrome in a mobile

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, web, favicon

Hi I have put all the exact code to show a favicon. Its working when i try to save the page using a firefox browser. The icon is showing up in my home screen. But if i do the same with a chrome browser, im getting a round square with an alphabet in it. The site i have is run using wordpress. What exactly is the problem ??

I have put the following codes :

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.coconutlodge.com/skin/images/favicon.png" type="image/png" />    
    <link href="http://www.coconutlodge.com/skin/images/icon76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" />
    <link href="http://www.coconutlodge.com/skin/images/icon120.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" />
    <link href="http://www.coconutlodge.com/skin/images/icon152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />
    <link href="http://www.coconutlodge.com/skin/images/icon180.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" />
    <link href="http://www.coconutlodge.com/skin/images/icon192.png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192" type="image/png" />
    <link href="http://www.coconutlodge.com/skin/images/icon128.png" rel="icon" sizes="128x128" type="image/png" />
```

i have also added :

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

jst to force everything to work

Comment: where is your code ??

Comment: can you see now in the question ??

Comment: yaaa i have done tat

Comment: 1st time posting a question... :)sooo

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755943/favicon-start-sreens-for-all-browsers-and-devices